# How to resolve C++ Error C2039 using Sciplot modern C++ library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

I just tried to use Sciplot for C++ found here:
https://sciplot.github.io/

Using Visual Studio Community 2017.
Copied the sciplot folder of headers into my dependencies folder of project.
Added include folders into project settings.
Copied the example code provided on their git.

```
#include <sciplot/sciplot.hpp>
using namespace sciplot;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Create values for your x-axis
    const vec x = linspace(0.0, 5.0, 100);

    // Create a plot object
    plot plt;

    // Set color palette
    plt.palette("set2");

    // Draw a sine graph putting x on the x-axis and sin(x) on the y-axis
    plt.draw(x, std::sin(x)).title("sin(x)").linewidth(4);

    // Draw a cosine graph putting x on the x-axis and cos(x) on the y-axis
    plt.draw(x, std::cos(x)).title("cos(x)").linewidth(4);

    // Show the plot in a popup window
    plt.show();

    // Save the plot to a PDF file
    plt.save("figure.pdf");
}
```

It throws this error.

...\dependencies\sciplot\util.hpp(285): error C2039: 'remove_if': is not a member of 'std'

...\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\valarray(16): note: see declaration of 'std'

...\dependencies\sciplot\util.hpp(285): error C3861: 'remove_if': identifier not found

Microsoft docs said to try putting the  found in the util.hpp inside namespace std but that did not work.
I also tried setting the language standard to C++14 , C++17 and latest and to blank in the project settings because the git said it requires C++14 (or higher I think).

Thank you for feedback.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't do *Copied the sciplot folder of headers into my dependencies folder of project.*. Place the headers somewhere central and point projects at that central location. Helps reduce sprawl and duplication across projects.

Comment: Oops - I said:  "Microsoft docs said to try putting the found in the util.hpp inside namespace std".  But I mean that inside util.hpp , I went to where it has #include <cstdlib> and put the #include inside namespace std.

Comment: [Update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66180263/edit). Comments are too ephemeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the C2039 error:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sciplot/sciplot.hpp>
using namespace sciplot;
```